# suggest open source project or free software to visualize sensor data like IMU or distance sensor

Tags: 3d, data-visualization, microcontroller, sensors, imu

I am working on a project where I'll be dealing with IMUs, servos and distance sensors. I would like to calibrate them before I use them in final version.

I am looking for a 3D visualizer where I can give live sensor input and 3D object moves or rotates. any suggestions?

Thank you

Comment: Not open source but free: FreeMASTER (NXP).  Paid: LabVIEW

Comment: @tonypdmtr thanks mate!!

Comment: @tonypdmtr also heard about Unity gaming engine. But it requires a bit knowledge of how to use it and software is kinds heavy